# Inequalities involving $\mathrm{exp}()$ and factorial of natural numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I have the following math problem that I got stuck on:
Proof that the following inequalities hold for all $n \in \mathbb{N}:$
$$n^{n} * \exp(-n  + 1) \leq n! \leq n^{n+1} * \exp(-n + 1)$$

My idea was to use induction, but I have trouble finding the step from $n$ to $n+1$.
$$(n+1)^{n+1} * \exp(-(n+1) + 1) \leq (n+1)!$$
Can be rewritten as:
$$(n+1)^{n} * (n+1) * \exp(-n) \leq n! * (n+1)$$
Which can be simplified (or atleast I hope it can) to:
$$(n+1)^{n} * \exp(-n) \leq n!$$
But then I have no idea how to proceed, let alone do the second inequality.

Comment: Hint: For the RHS, use the fact that $[ \frac{n+1}{n}]^{n+1} > e$. Do something similar for the LHS.